# CSS margin-left is breaking in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

My situation is extremely confusing, and I haven't the slightest clue what's going on. I made a Firefox add-on to redesign a website using jQuery and CSS. When I tried to migrate the addon to Chrome (that part was simple, because the features I am using in each SDK are very similar), everything worked except one of the main design elements:

I have a menu with `position: fixed;` aligned to the left of the page, and `margin-left: 150px;` on the main container element. The problem is that the `margin` is completely disappearing when I open it in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox.

So then I copied all of the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into a jsFiddle, and the margin worked fine. Everything was completely identical, so I can't figure out why it would work in jsFiddle but not on the website.

Using `left: 150px` works, but then the page spills 150px to the right, and those dreaded horizontal scrollbars appear.

Links:

Extension File (CRX): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3k3BjZD2YfiTWNzTlhsa0t5STg

Demo Website: http://demo.flvs.net (Username: demo, Password: demo)

jsFiddle (Some images don't load, but the code is identical): http://jsfiddle.net/CjSXA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just removed the margin-left from #page_cont and added it to #content-cont.

That made the content stop hiding under the menu, though the footer is still partially covered by it.

Comment: OK, I will try that as soon as I get a chance. Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: Sorry, not sure to be honest, I didn't have much of a look at the footer.

Comment: OK, so I ended up putting the margin on `#page_cont` and changing footer to: `width: auto; right: 0; left: 0; margin-left: 150px;`, which seems to solve all the problems.